# Given $\frac{dy}{dx} = x\sqrt{y-3}$, can we guarantee that there exists a unique solution on some neighborhood about $y(4) =3$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Given $\frac{dy}{dx} = x\sqrt{y-3}$, can we guarantee that there exists a unique solution on some neighborhood about $y(4) =3$?

Note that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is continous at $y(4) = 3$ while $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ ${x\sqrt{y-3}} = \frac{x}{2\sqrt{y-3}}$ is not continuous at $y(4) = 3$. What does the existence and uniqueness theorem tell us?

Answer (score 1):

This won't answer your question, but the solution is *not* unique. You have a family of non-trivial solutions

$$ y(x) = \begin{cases} 3, & x \le a \\ 3 + \dfrac{(x^2-a^2)^2}{16}, & x > a \end{cases} $$

where $a \ge 4$

If $a=4$ then this solution is not constant on any neighborhood around $x=4$